# How to include Jquery matchMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this script to only fire when widths greater than 1024px's is found but I'm not having any luck getting to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)').matches) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dar').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn(800);
        }, 400);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#email-header').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn(800);
        }, 800);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#smiley').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn(800);
        }, 1200);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#header-child').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn(800);
        }, 1600);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.links').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn(800);
        }, 2000);

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you include your html? I plugged just your media query into this [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/meyRwE) and it worked fine. I think there must be some kind of problem with calling an element in your html

Comment: @PeteTalksWeb Ah, it was an extra bracket in my html that was messing it up.